# Loose mouse support in view

Tags: vim, mouse

If I run `vim` normally, I get mouse support (via `set mouse=a`). However, if I run vim as `view`, it appears to not load my .vimrc correctly.

```
[c34n11 colors] vim elflord.vim      # runs correctly
[c34n11 colors] view elflord.vim     # gives error, no mouse
Error detected while processing /gpfs/loomis/home.grace/fas/manohar/emb99/.vimrc:
    line    2:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
Press ENTER or type command to continue
[c34n11 colors] which view
/usr/bin/view
[c34n11 colors] file /usr/bin/view   # view just points to vim
/usr/bin/view: symbolic link to `vi'
[c34n11 colors] which vi
alias vi='vim'
        /usr/bin/vim
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/bin/vi` is a lightweight version of Vim, which likely doesn't support a lot of things like colorschemes, syntax highlighting, etc.  Obviously `/usr/bin/vim` is the full version that does.

The fact that you have aliased `vi` to `vim` doesn't affect symbolic links.

The way I solve this is to set an alias in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias view="vim -R"
```

Also, there's a trick you can do in your `~/.vimrc` to prevent the stripped down version of Vim from giving you errors when it sources.  Just put an `if 1` before the commands that only work in the full version of Vim, such as before your `set mouse=a` command.  For example:

```
set showcmd
set hlsearch
set ignorecase

if 1
set mouse=1
syntax on
filetype indent plugin on
endif
```

Comment: Does vim run in compatibility mode when run as vi?

Comment: @baum It's more that many distributions install a /bin/vi that is compiled without most of the extended features of Vim. It's not that it's running in compatibility mode, it's that it's literally incapable of more.

Comment: But on my system, `which vi` gave `alias vi='vim'`...

Comment: Yes, but that does not and can not affect symlinks. view is pointed to vi via symlink, so it's going to invoke vi, bypassing the alias. This is why I suggested adding another alias.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Totally misread that.